# If my astral and causal bodies are within me, how they are controlling my luck 1000 miles away?

Tags: gita

My causal and astral bodies are within myself, so it is easy to believe that they are giving me either luck or unluck.

But if I participate in a 100 billion dollar lottery in USA then how Astral and Causal bodies which are with me in India are controlling my chances of winning that lottery?

1. The connectivity between lottery and me is the nature so is it nature storing my information which are impacting my luck and not my inner bodies?

(or)

2. I will make a thought about that lottery within me then my Astral and Causal bodies sharing about it to the nature which in turn impacting my chances of winning the lottery? Should I simply stop thinking to avoid impact on the lottery?

There is a belief that one should have positive thinking then positive results will some, so my 2nd assumption is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Astral and Causal bodies have nothing to do with luck, but karmas do. Yes, the karmas are stored in your causal body but it itself isn't what determining your luck. 
Your luck is determined by the Astrological positions you were born in. The karmas of your previous life determines the birth of your current life through astrology. Good graha positions, good life & luck. It is Daiva. If it is in your fate to have massive amount money through lottery, you will. Otherwise, not.
Although, it is possible to change your luck to some extent by the help of Deva-Devis and through your own karma (of this life). Regarding your second question, it might be possible for mind to interact with real life events through thoughts, because the world itself is an emanation of the Cosmic mind, which is connected to your mind. Though, it is not possible always. You see, positive thinking doesn't always bring positive results. Or, should I say it is upon you how to perceive the results. All depends on you perception. If you can see the bright sides of the results, then it IS positive for you. Karma decides some aspects of life, not all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).